# Produce excel file from python that has two columns from a list

Tags: python

I have two variables that both have sentences, which I want to then save into a new excel file where each sentence is in a different column. I get a 'list' object has no attribute 'items'.

This is what I have written:

```
Use = The dog was sleeping.
Strength = The cat was awake.
volume = [Use, Strength]
!pip install xlsxwriter

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Jaspersoft.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

worksheet.write('A1', 'Dog', bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'Cat', bold)

row = 1
col = 0

for case, top in volume.items:
    worksheet.write(row, col, case)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, top)
    row +=1

workbook.close()
```

Want an excel file that has two columns with headers of Dog and Cat, then underneath the dog column would have the dog sentence and the cat column should have the cat sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Use = "The dog was sleeping."
Strength = "The cat was awake."

volume = [Use, Strength]

!pip install xlsxwriter
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Jaspersoft.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

worksheet.write('A1', 'Dog', bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'Cat', bold)

row = 1
col = 0

for i, sentence in enumerate(volume):
    worksheet.write(row, col + i, sentence)

row +=1
workbook.close()
```